# PLSQL: How to get the latest records over several versions

Tags: plsql, group-by, max

I have a table with multiple description versions, and need to get the latest description according to field VALFR.
This is what I have:

```html
OBJECT_ID   VALFR           DESCRIPTION
2000022732  20.140.527.170.800  IRN 50624 SOFPHONE CIPC CISCO IP COMMUNI
2000022732  20.140.527.171.235  IRN 50624 SOFPHONE CIPC CISCO
2000022732  20.140.725.193.455  IRN 50624 CISCO IP COMMUNICATOR
2000033166  20.130.926.150.207  IRN 11950 SAP MERCOSUR
2000033184  20.140.527.185.736  IRN 70004 MATERIEL
2000033184  20.140.530.193.807  IRN 70004 MATERIEL
2000033184  20.140.728.114.539  IRN 70004 MATERIALES
```

This is what I need:

```html
2000033166  20.130.926.150.207  IRN 11950 SAP MERCOSUR
2000022732  20.140.725.193.455  IRN 50624 CISCO IP COMMUNICATOR
2000033184  20.140.728.114.539  IRN 70004 MATERIALES
```

I just can't get MAX() and GROUP BY OBJECT_ID to work together...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may work;

```
SELECT T1.* FROM table_name T1,
(select T2.OBJECT_ID,MAX(T2.VALFR) FROM table_name T2 GROUP BY T2.OBJECT_ID) AS T3
WHERE T1.OBJECT_ID = T3.OBJECT_ID AND T1.VALFR = T3.VALFR
```

Comment: I made it with a left join on T1, then it worked! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I solved this in the best way, but using a LEFT JOIN on the text table solved the problem.
But I probably wouldn't get there without Serif Emek's help!
Thank you very much!